# Комбинаторика. Перестановки

Tags: математика, комбинаторика

Вопрос по какой формуле можно сосчитать все возможные варианты?
Пример.
Есть 34 символа. Их нужно распределить по пакетам в 100 символов. Вот сколько вообще таких пакетов будет?
Понятно что символы будут повторяться. Это не важно.

Comment: Приведите пример для небольших чисел, чтобы было понятно, что значит "распределить". Например, a, b, c  и пакет 5

Comment: На пример. На цифрах приведу. Возьмём 34 первых числа. Получается первый пакет будет состоять из 100 единиц. Второй из 100 двоек. Потом единиц и двоек и семерок на пример. Сколько вообще таких пакетов будет.

Comment: Штош... Надеюсь, вы спрашивали именно о том, что вам ответили.

Comment: @MBo Насколько был для меня понятен вопрос, настолько и ответил, вроде все верно))

Comment: @DanilaKartovitskii Да к ответу претензий нет. Просто были сомнения, как именно могут выглядеть распределения, какие считать разными и т.п.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Эта формула носит название *числа сочетаний с повторениями* из **n**
объектов по **k**. Она описывает, сколькими способами можно составить комбинацию по **k**
элементов из элементов **n**
типов.

Comment: Спасибо. n получается это 34. А k это 100. Правильно я понял.

Comment: Все верно)
Пожалуйста, если ответ Вам помог и больше вопросов нет, нажмите галочку рядом с ответом :)